# Re-usable bundle and entities inheritance

Tags: symfony, architecture, bundle

Today, I'm faced with a conceptual problem ; I am developing a web application linked to education, where users will be training themself with multiple question choice forms.

It's a project that may be recurrent, 'cause it will probably lead to some other projects around the same idea, but a little derived.

In order to be more efficient next time, I would like to do a re-usable bundle for MQC forms ; I have my architecture right in my head, that doesn't depend of any other entities in the application, unless User. This one isn't the problem, 'cause it's just part of a relation and I think I can pass it as parameter.

The biggest problem here, is that : I have in this specific application created a generic entities reprenseting "content types", and containing some important informations that all other entities in the application should share. The problem is, my base class in the re-usable bundle should also inherits from this generic class..

And that's where I'm struck : how to define something generic, but in this specific case make it inherits from one of my application entity ? Is it even possible, or real bad conception ?
Maybe I should use an intermediary class, and add a relation with all of my other entities, but then I wouldn't be able to select many different content types together (for history purpose, for example)...

Thanks by advance

Comment: Not a lot of details in your question but as a rule, avoid inheritance across bundles.  Aim for some sort of composition.  As far as history goes, you often want data in a different format for long term purposes so think in terms of archiving.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understood your question correctly but you may find help in this **[cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your idea right, I'll advice to you following solution:
I'll post code from my some re-usable bundle "CustomerReviewBundle", so I think you will be able to adapt it easy for your case:

1. Create an interface at re-usable bundle `ProductInterface`

   ```
   interface ProductInterface
   {

   }
   ```
2. Then you can create an entity at your re-usable bundle with reference to `ContentTypeInterface`

   ```
   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
   use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
   use \Gamma\CustomerReview\CustomerReviewBundle\Interfaces\ProductInterface;

   /**
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gamma\CustomerReview\CustomerReviewBundle\Repository\CustomerReviewRepository")
    * @ORM\Table(name="customer_review", indexes={
    * @ORM\Index(name="enabled_idx", columns={"enabled"}),
    * @ORM\Index(name="rating_idx", columns={"enabled", "rating"}),
    * @ORM\Index(name="sort_idx", columns={"date"})
    * })
    */
   class CustomerReview
   {
   ....
   other properties
   ...
       /**
        * Product
        *
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gamma\CustomerReview\CustomerReviewBundle\Interfaces\ProductInterface")
        */
       private $product; 
   ....
   getters/setters
   ...
   }
   ```
3. Then I connect my re-usable bundle at my app

And can define which exactly product type can by used for reviews by follow setting at config.yml

```
doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        # ...
        resolve_target_entities:
             Gamma\CustomerReview\CustomerReviewBundle\Interfaces\ProductInterface: \MyApp\ProductBundle\Entity\Product
```

So you can do same way, just change Product to your `ContentType` class, and then you can define certain content types for each your app that uses your re-usable bundle

More info http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html